# Magento 2: Subtract commission To The Store from the grand total

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I have added a custom fee as commission on my checkout total, All are working fine while checkout but I want to subtract the commission value from grand total for some payment gateway. On My payment gateway I have amount parameter as mentioned below.

Code is   `$amount = (int) (number_format($mazeOrder->getGrandTotal() * 100, 0, ".", ""));`

Here I want to get this custom fee and subtract that form the grand total. How can I get my custom fee on Controller.

[image]

Comment: In your code getCommissionTotal() is Parameter or function? Can you echo or print the value of the commission total? I assume that the commission_total column is present in the sales order table then you can use the same object to fetch the value of the commission total for ex: $mazeOrder->getCommissionTotal()

Comment: Hi @JitendraPatel, I have edited my question for better information

Comment: On which table custom fee is saved or stored? Can you confirm the table name?

Comment: I have added this as product custom option so it is showing there on my product_option on sales_order_item table, Here is the saved data

'{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9sb29tdG9ob21lLmNvbS9vcmFuZ2Utc2VtaS1zaWxrLXNhcmVlLXdpdGgtY29udHJhc3QtcGFsbHUtd2l0aC16YXJpLWFuZC10aHJlYWQtd29ya2VkLWJvcmRlci5odG1s","product":"185","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","item":"185","check_commission":"1","money":"148.5","qty":"1"}}'

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order item data(custom fee) value by using the order repository class in your controller class as below.

Step 1: Add Order Repository class as the below dependency.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Step 2: Fetch the order data by order id as below.

```
   try {
      $order = $this->orderRepository->get($your_order_id);
      foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
        echo $_item->getYourCustomFee(); // Change with your custom fee column name & then do your logic.
      }
   } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
      throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('This order no longer exists.'));
   }
```